# Vuejs SSR, Laravel and PHP V8Js issue "window is undefined"

Tags: javascript, php, typescript, laravel-5, vuejs2

I am trying to render server side code on page load by following https://medium.com/js-dojo/advanced-server-side-rendering-with-laravel-vue-multi-page-app-486b706e654 . Everything works fine but when I try to use global variable "window" or "document"

my `app.js` code is

```
import App from './components/App.vue';
import Vue from 'vue';
import { createRouter } from './router'
import { createStore } from './store'
import { sync } from 'vuex-router-sync'
require('./bootstrap');
```

The bootstrap.js is normal as

```
window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

I need axios globally but php V8Js gives error

`V8Js::compileString():612: TypeError: window is undefined`

I found that `V8Js` doesn't have browser variables and I tried using npm package `browser-env` but getting same error. see the screenshot http://nimb.ws/zGDmXO

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you have to get rid from `windows` and `document` using for the `JS` string that you are passing to `V8Js::executeString` because it looks for `document` and `window` but it doesn't exists that time and code is executing at the server-end.

In your `app.js`
Do something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

and at back-end do like:

```
$rendererSrc =\file_get_contents()(\base_path('node_modules/vue-server-renderer/basic.js'));
$appSrc = file_get_contents()(\public_path('js/entry-server.js'));
$v8Js = new \V8Js();
$v8Js->executeString(
                <<<EOT
    var process = { env: { VUE_ENV: "server", NODE_ENV: "production" } }; 
    this.global = { process: process };
    var url = "path_you_are_hitting";
    {$rendererSrc}
    {$appSrc}
EOT
);
```

Hope it'll work

Comment: Yes but what if want to use localStorage because it is also not defined

Comment: The server knows nothing about localStorage. You'll have to use cookies.